# Return a single value and multiple OUT parameter in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I read an article about Stored Procedures which said:

> A stored procedure can return a single values such as a number or text value or a result set

I am confused, because if we declare multiple OUT parameters, the we can have multiple output but it said that we can have only a single value?

EDIT:

This is [The Article](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-a-stored-procedure/)

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are completely different.

Comment: In addition to a tag for actual DBMS you are using, add a link to the article you quoted.

Comment: "a single values"? That doesn't even make sense; a singular value can't be many (values is plural, not singular). It's like saying "I have 1 books" or "I have a single TVs". And a result set is normally far from a single value (though it can only contain one, or none).

Comment: @DaleK are they different?

Comment: @DaleK yes. https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-a-stored-procedure/

Comment: @Larnu In the cited article, it really reads "A stored procedure can return a single value**s**". (plonk!)

Comment: @DanGuzman ok. I edited my post and added the link of the article.

Comment: @MehSar thats a sloppy article badly written. I'd ignore it.

Comment: This article is not good. Better start with reading the original documentation from Microsoft.

Comment: When I Google "Stored Procedure" it's the first link I get. :'( i agree though, start with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/stored-procedures-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu Exactly! that's because i got confused :(

Comment: @DaleK yes. I didn't know that and just started to read and got confused. :(

Comment: @SQLPolice yes.  I didn't know that and just started to read and got confused. :( is the Documentation clear and helpful for a beginner?

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the link. is the documentation helpful for me as a beginner?

Comment: Very helpful @MehSar . It should honestly be your first port of call when you wonder how syntax, an object or function, etc, works. SQL Server's documentation is both Microsoft and Community maintained, so it's always being improved.

Comment: @MehSar, in summary, a stored procedure returns data in the form of result sets and output parameters. Although it is possible to return integer data using the return code, it's best to use the return code only to denote success (zero) or failure(non-zero). Applications typically don't examine the return code and assume errors will be raised when problems occur.

Comment: There is maybe a kind of misunderstanding. A stored procedure first "returns" a dataset, which is the result of a SELECT statement in your procedure. In addition, it can return a value like INT, which is returned by statement RETURN. And then, it also can have OUT parameters. So at the same time, it can "return" multiple values and datasets in different ways.

Comment: @SQLPolice not only, but it can return multiple datasets if desired. And important for OP to note, this question is only talking about SQL Server whereas the article in question was talking about SPs generally across various RDBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, a stored procedure can actually return a value -- always an integer.  This is usually a status value and is quite separate from the `output` parameters.

So you can can have:

```
execute @retval = usp_myproc @x1 output, @x2 output;
```

The returned value is generally not data, but a status.

Comment: I don't think the uncited article the OP is referencing means the `RETURN` value, as `RETURN` cannot return a string based data type or  result set. If the article does mean `RETURN`, then it's just plain wrong.

Answer (score -2):

That statement is not entirely correct.

> There are three ways of returning data from a procedure to a calling program: result sets, output parameters, and return codes.

See [Return Data from a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#returning-data-using-an-output-parameter)

This link will walk you through the 3 approaches.

Comment: Thats not accurate or helpful.